# How to prove that there is no infinite arithmetic progression of perfect squares

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, contest-math

How to prove that there is no infinite arithmetic progression of perfect squares

This question from a school Olympiad paper !

How can I prove this directly or using contradiction ?

For example : 1 ,25 , 49 are perfect squares and has 24 as the differnce ! but not infinite !

Comment: Hint: Consider the arithmetic progression $a,a+d,a+2d,a+3d,\dots$. If it has infinitely many perfect squares, it contains a perfect square $x^2\gt d^2$. Now look at $x^2+d$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $n^2 + d = m^2$ you get $(n-m)(n+m) = d$. For any fixed $d$ this limits the possible distinct values of $n,m$ to a finite collection. From this the claim follows quite directly.